# hang on an handler to an event handler in View

Tags: wpf, events, view, viewmodel

i want to add an event to my Event handler. The Problem is my EventHandler is in my ViewModel and my Event is in View. How can I access my ViewModel from View to hang on this event?

thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the view model is set as `DataContext` of the view you can subscribe to the `DataContextChanged` of the view and in the handler cast the `DataContext` to the view model's type and attach the desired event handler. Something like this:

```
public class MyView : UserControl
{
   public MyView()
   {
       InitializeComponent();

       DataContextChanged += OnDataContextChanged;
   }

   private void OnDataContextChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   {
      MyViewModel viewModel = DataContext as MyViewModel;

      if (viewModel != null) 
      {
          viewModel.MyEvent += OnMyEvent;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: how do you mean that. F.e. DataContextChanged(){...}

Comment: Note I need to change the signature to this: 
    private void OnDataContextChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)

Answer (score 1):

Usually in MVVM, when the View wants to defer some operation to the `ViewModel` it does so by binding to an ICommand. This is essentially the same usage model as with the event, as the View "pushes" the notification to the ViewModel.

Depending on the nature of the event I would suggest you look into doing it with an ICommand, since:

- The whole idea behind MVVM is for the ViewModel to *not* assume that the View is "real" UI
- Typically, however, the View *is* real UI (so the event you mention probably has to do with something happening in the UI)

Which leads me to think that you are searching for a way to have the ViewModel subscribe to a UI event from the View, something that would come contrary to the premise of MVVM.

Is invoking a command on the ViewModel problematic in your case?

Comment: Hi Jon, I have a Problem with changing my view. I have diffrent pages. I have a navigation Class where I navigate to every page. This navigation class is in my view, so I can´t call it from my ViewModel. I need this in my View because I´m passing some Objects to my new View, so I can´t take my navigation Class where my ViewModels are. I hope I have explained my problems.